# ActionView::MissingTemplate in Users#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been following an online tutorial, and I obviously have mistyped or have done something wrong. I know it is trying to render 'activities', but I don't know from where.

I'll add more details upon request.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial public_activity/post/_created with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/benjamin/Desktop/stukbook/app/views"
  * "/home/benjamin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-d3776ddd0b89/app/views"
  * "/home/benjamin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/app/views"
):
    55:         <div class="panel panel-default">
    56:         <div class="panel-heading">Recent Activity</div>
    57:         <div class="panel-body">
    58:             <%= render_activities(@activities) %>
    59:         </div>
    60:         </div>
    61:     </div>
```

My view/users/show.html:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <%= gravatar_tag @user.email, size: 200 %>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3><%= @user.username %></h3>
                <p>Age: <%= @user.age %></p>
                <p>Gender: <%= @user.gender %></p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3>Who am I</h3>
                <small><%= @user.bio %></small>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <!-- Friend Zone -->
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Friends (<%= @user.active_friends.size %>)
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">

    <% @user.active_friends.last(16).each do |user| %>
    <%= link_to user_path(user.username) do %>
        <%= gravatar_tag user.email, size: 40 %>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>

    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Post Zone -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <% if current_user && current_user == @user %>
    <%= render "posts/form" %>
    <% end %>
    <%= render @posts %>
    </div>
    <!-- Profile Activity -->
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Recent Activity</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <%= render_activities(@activities) %>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Users Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only:[:index]
    before_action :set_user, only:[:show]

    def index
        case params[:people] when "friends"
      @users = current_user.active_friends
    when "requests"
      @users = current_user.pending_friend_requests_from.map(&:user)
    when "pending"
      @users = current_user.pending_friend_requests_to.map(&:friend)
    else
      @users = User.where.not(id: current_user.id)
    end
    end

  def show
    @post = Post.new
    @posts = @user.posts.order('created_at DESC')
    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.where(owner_id: @user.id) +  PublicActivity::Activity.where(recipient_id: @user.id)
  end

  private

  def set_user
    @user = User.find_by(username: params[:id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial public_activity/post/_created with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/benjamin/Desktop/stukbook/app/views"
  * "/home/benjamin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-d3776ddd0b89/app/views"
  * "/home/benjamin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/app/views"
):
```

That first line is explaining everything you will need to debug the error.

```
Missing partial public_activity/post/_created
```

This line

```
 <%= render_activities(@activities) %>
```

is looking in the directory path below for the file titled "_created"

```
public_activity/post/_created
```

If that path and file do not exists but you wish to use the route you have set up create the folders you need (public_activity would be the first, post would be inside that and then inside the post folder you would need the file _created.html.erb)  The underscore to start out is required.

Comment: Your amazing. I deleted the _created.html.erb file for some reason. I'll mark it as correct when they allow me to on the timer!

Comment: Where in the error did you realize it was looking for the _created file? Unless I can't see correctly :/ Or is that just personal knowledge?

Comment: ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial public_activity/post/_created ...)  What this is say is that it is missing a partial at the route following it.